# A note on perfect ideals

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, paper-request

I am reading an article that cites this note:

E.S. Golod, A note on perfect ideals, in: A.I. Kostrikin (Ed.), Algebra Collection, Nauka, Moscow, 1980,
pp. 37–39.

E. S. Golod, A note on perfect ideals, in "Algebra" (ed. A. I. Kostrikin), translation by L. L.
Avramov. Moscow State University.

Does someone have access to this notes?

Comment: At least it is reviewd in ZbMath https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0496.13009

Comment: The corresponding question on [math.se]: [A note on perfect ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4475047).